# Usage of already deployed REST service in mobile application using IBM Mobile First

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I've published a native android application which uses a services with response in JSON format. Now, I want to develop a Hybrid application using IBM Mobile first platform. I want to use the same service here in this case also. I'm not able to findout the mechanism to do so. Anyone please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0, both the JS framework (for Hybrid apps) and the Native SDK (for iOS and Android) provide REST support. You can accomplish this using either JavaScript adapters or Java adapters.

Read the following tutorials explaining how to use MFP adapters:

- [Server-side development](https://web.archive.org/web/20151009151714/https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/)

If you're interested in Java adapters as well, take a look at these videos as well:

- [Getting familiar with IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation Java Adapters [Part 1]](https://web.archive.org/web/20151026203636/https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/24/getting-familiar-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-java-adapters/)
- [Getting familiar with IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation Java Adapters [Part 2]](https://web.archive.org/web/20151026203636/https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/27/getting-familiar-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-java-adapters-part-2/)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you intend to build your hybrid app using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

You could directly call the service using standard JavaScript

```
 XMLHttpRequest(serviceUrl)
```

But you probably will use some framework such as AngularJS - such frameworks really do pay off in the long run - and in which case you have nice APIs

```
$http.get(serviceUrl).then(doSomeWork);
```

However this raw JavaScript approach does not exploit the MobileFirst programming model. We tend to find that using a Mobile Gateway architectural pattern, where MobileFirst adapters act as the gateway, pays off as your application becomes more complex. The adapters provide a security model and can implement aggregation and filtering so that precious mobile bandwidth is used more efficiently.

Hence we recommend that you build adapters, as described in the links given by Idan, and then you use the MobileFirst API to call the adapters:

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure( ... );
```